Declaring a variable of unknown value in Python
I want to create a variable called this_is_the_first_run which will be stored in the 'main.py' file and it should indicate whether this is the first time the project is run. Basically, code I'm trying to write look like this:
If this_is_the_first_run == 1:
os.system('python first_run.py')

But I don't know where to assign and store this variable as I can't put it in my 'first_run.py'. Neither can I assign value to this variable somewhere in the main file.
What is the best approach to that?

So, you know the value. It's a boolean that's either True or False based on storing run information somewhere. Python won't do that for you, of course, that would be really strange (why would it count how many times it's been asked to run something?) The simplest solution is to just create a file: if it doesn't exist, first run. If it done, then obviously your script already ran in the past. And a smart programmer would make that a config file that, if it doesn't exist, gets created with sensible defaults.

Variables generated during code execution do not, by themselves, have an existence that endures beyond the execution of your code. If you want the values of variables to persist beyond code execution, you need to write the values you wish to endure to a file on disc, and then access/read/write those files as part of your code execution.
An example of how you can achieve what you're describing is given below:
# This is the main function. Each time it's run, the variable "run_count" is 
# retrieved by reading run_count.txt, and its value is incremented by 1, and
# written back to run_count.txt. 

def main():
    
    # check if "run_count.txt" exists. If it does, read its current count and 
    # assign it to the variable run_count. 
    try:
        with open('run_count.txt', 'r') as f:
            run_count = int(f.read())   
    
    # If run_count.txt does not yet exist, create it and write the value 0 to it.
    except FileNotFoundError:
        
        with open('run_count.txt', 'w') as f:
            run_count = 0
            f.write(str(run_count))
        
    # Insert actual main() code here:
    print ("Now the script does whatever you want.")
    
    # Now that your main() function has been run, increment the value of run_count
    # by 1 and write the new value to run_count.txt.    
    run_count += 1
    
    with open('run_count.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(run_count))

    # print the current run_count to screen        
    print(f'This script has been run {run_count} {"times." if run_count > 1 else "time."}')
    
main()
# Now the script does whatever you want.
# This script has been run 1 time.
main()
# Now the script does whatever you want.
# This script has been run 2 times.
main()
# Now the script does whatever you want.
# This script has been run 3 times.
main()
# Now the script does whatever you want.
# This script has been run 4 times.
main()
# Now the script does whatever you want.
# This script has been run 5 times.

In this case, a single value is written to a txt file. If you wanted multiple values, or more complex data structures to endure, there is a host of options available - from using larger/longer txt files, csvs, jsons, or databases.

I strongly recommend against using plain text files for storing data. Using int() is an extremely bad idea because if the file contain a newline then it will break down.

Certainly, a text file is not the best way to save data - I have used it here to introduce the asker to the basic notion of reading/writing files as a way to make values persist. From the question, I have inferred that "json" may be a new concept to the user, and have tried to keep it basic.

Python variables are only defined when a given program is being run, and disappear immediately the moment the program finishes execution. If you want a variable to live beyond the current executing program, try using json and files, like this:
import json
import os

if os.path.exists(path:=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'run_times.json')):
    with open(path, 'r') as fp:
        times = json.load(fp)+1
        print(f'executed this file {times} times')
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(times, fp)
else:
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(1, fp)
        print(f'executed this file 1 time')

# do what you want here

This approach is reliable and adaptable to all kind of operating systems, conditions, and objects. Using json is better than using plain text files because you can rely on the library to extract the values, rather than extracting the values yourself. Also, the above code uses the os library to check if the file exists. Although trying to open the file and catching FileNotFoundError works, it raises unnecessary exceptions. Thus, I suggest using the json library to handle the data and the os library to check if the file exists, rather than raising an exception.

Raising and catching exceptions is the Python way, no need to be afraid of it.

No need for JSON if you just want a marker that indicates your script's already run. You can just create an empty .run file. You only need json (or pickle, or at the very least explicit file writing) if you want to count more than just "is this the first time my script has run", but the question was pretty clear about that.

But for any slightly more complex scenarios json would be a requirement. Also, my interpretation of OP's question is how to show how many number of times this file was executed, not just a Boolean value of whether this file had been executed before or not. Although I may be wrong, my solution nonetheless adds additional functionality which is usually appreciated.

This behavior could be achieved by using a config file. To distinguish between the first run and the subsequent runs you can just use the existence of the config file as an indicator.
import json
import pathlib

# the config file is in the same directory as this python file
config_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'config.json'

# equivalent but, the config file is stored in the same directory
# as the __main__ python file, e.g. if you run `python index.py` then index.py is __main__.py
config_path = pathlib.Path('config.json')

# if file doesn't exist,
# assuming it wasn't deleted by user previously
# then this is definitely the first run
first_run = not config_path.exists()

if first_run:
    # it is important to create the file on the first run
    with config_path.open('wt') as f:
        f.write("{}")  # empty json
        # equivalent line using a dictionary
        json.dump({}, f)

        # do your other stuff



The question needs a complete, through, but simple answer, which I do not think pathlib is. Most Python programmers know how to use json, but not pathlib. Also, your code contains many duplicates. For example, f.write("{}") and json.dump({}, f) are doing the same thing, just in different ways. Consider using only json.dump().

@LukeL The reason I used pathlib and have duplicated code is that I tried to be more informative in my answer. And yes, f.write("{}") and json.dump({}, f) are doing the same thing. For the problem at hand, I think the former is better, while the latter is the extendable and flexible version that I only added to suggest as an alternative. Best regards.

@LukeL, you are absolutely right when you said I should have made my answer straight and simple.
